# RaspberryPi LAMP only opens the default virtualhost

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, lamp, virtual-hosts

I have a problem with my LAMP setup on my RaspberryPi.
LAMP installed using this http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/raspberrypi-webserver.
OS: 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.

The problem is that it only uses the default virtualhost. I've set up 2 custom Vhosts as described below.

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
This is not touched since install.

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" $
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combin$ 
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer 
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent Include conf.d/ Include sites-enabled/
```

I've also tried with:

```
HostnameLookups Off
```

Added file /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn at some point when troublshooting:

```
ServerName raspberrypi
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/custom-config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/me
        ServerName      www.mydomain.se
        ServerAlias     mydomain.se

        <Directory /var/www/html/me/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/log/me/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/www/log/me/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/other
        ServerName      www.mysubdomain.mydomain.se
        ServerAlias     mysubdomain.mydomain.se

        <Directory /var/www/html/other/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/log/other/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/www/log/other/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My custom-config is added with a2ensite.

The /var/www/ looks like

```
html/
    me/
    other/
log/
    me/
    other/
```

Folder permissions, and here I've seen many people taking ownership and changing permissions but every forum post has its own rules it seems so I've just left it as is.
Maybe this could be something but wouldn't apache have logged som access error in that case?

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 16 21:56 html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 16 22:02 me
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 16 20:07 other

drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 18 12:11 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 18 12:12 me
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 18 12:12 other
```

I also have found a suspicious log entry in /var/log/apache2/access.log:

```
xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.customer.t3.se - - [18/Jan/2014:14:00:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
```

Where "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" is my public IP(replaced) and ".customer.t3.se" is my ISP, shouldn't this have been something like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.mydomain.se"?

Well that's about it, any help would be appreciated and more info is available if it helps.
And finally, yes I've serched and tried different solutions without progress...for hours!

Comment: You need to disable the default configuration `a2dissite default` and then reload or restart Apache.

Comment: Isn't the default supposed to be there to handle requests that doesn't meet the "filters"?

Comment: No, in fact its what preventing your site from working because its catching the incoming requests.

Comment: Ok, done that, now it opens when using my domain but not when I'm trying my subdomain. My guess is becouse now the configuration for www.mydomain.se becomes the default entry?